# Opencv (python) finding true positive in binary images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have two binary images one as [ground truth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoZ3B.jpg) and other as [experimental/testing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHLjf.jpg). I want to calculate true positive,  false positive and false negative where my region of interest is blobs (i.e. circle and ellipse) present in the images.

For the true positive, the intersection of images using 'or bitwise' operation was performed along with counting a total of black pixels present in the intersected image as 'Total number of True Positive pixels',i.e, TP.

For false positive, pixels having value 255 in the ground-truth image was considered and a total of white pixels assigned as'Total number of False Positive',i.e, FP

For false negative pixels having value 255 in experimental-image was considered and a total of white pixels assigned as 'Total number of False Negative',i.e., FN

Precision and Recall is calculated as:

> Precision as TP / (TP + FP)
>
> Recall as TP / (TP + FN)

It seems the values are calculated wrong as I got precision to be 19%.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really a programming question as it is more a "math" one. I was sort of lost in you computing of FP and FN. Futher confused by the fact that your images seem to be "a black object on a white bg", while we usually go the other way around (but that is up to you).
Anyway, if you say G is ground truth, G-1 its inverse, E experimental and E-1 its inverse, then the number of white pixels in the following images will give you the correct values : G and E : TP ; G-1 and E-1 : TN; G-1 and E : FP; G and E-1 : FN

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to an other stack exchange site

Comment: @Soltius Thanks for the answer!!